# Syntax error missing operator need help in between date

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
public void FillPresentDays()
{
    con.Open();

    cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(*) from AttendanceDatabase  WHERE EmpName =@EmpName and Status =@Status and WHERE Date between @d1 and @d2", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", txtEmpName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtP.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", dtDate1.Value.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", dtDate2.Value.Date);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    txtPdays.Text = count.ToString();
    con.Close();
}
```

Badly need help for the query

Comment: Try putting a space after your `=` signs in the query.

Comment: i think two where clause is the problem

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Syntax error, missing operator. But i already solved it thanks to sumeet kumar :)) Btw Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Said same as comment extra where clause try the below

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(*) from AttendanceDatabase  WHERE EmpName =@EmpName and Status =@Status and Date between @d1 and @d2", con)
```

Answer (score 1):

You query is incorrect. the `WHERE` clause can only appear once in single query.

Change:

```
Select COUNT(*) from AttendanceDatabase WHERE EmpName =@EmpName and Status =@Status and WHERE Date between @d1 and @d2"
```

to:

```
Select COUNT(*) from AttendanceDatabase  WHERE EmpName =@EmpName and Status =@Status and Date between @d1 and @d2"
```

Answer (score 0):

`and WHERE` is incorrect syntax.

You can only have one `WHERE` clause.

Comment: how can i search the total number of present days in between by two dates?